# nohup re-executes the process after ending

Tags: python, training-data, nohup

I am training some models with **nohup**, I have set 100 epochs, after completing 100 epochs it automatically restarts the command, and the training re-executes with 0th epoch until I kill nohup process.
Can someone answer what should I do to automatically turn off nohup reaching the 100th epoch?

Comment: Nohup doesn't automatically rerun things. You'll need to show your code and how you're running it.

Comment: A [mre] would probably be the most helpful thing here -- the simplest possible code that causes the same problem when someone who's not you runs it.